# How can I create a diagram to compare skyline operation results using LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, technical-drawing

I'm trying to draw this but except for the straight lines in this diagram I'm not able to place other things such as square and circle properly. How can I do this? Help much appreciated.

[image: example of what I would like to achieve]

EDIT:
Since MWE is asked I'll post here my code and update it as and when I get close to the picture above.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=.2cm, x=.7cm,font=\sffamily]
    \draw (0,0) -- coordinate (x axis mid) (10,0);
    \draw (0,0) -- coordinate (y axis mid) (0,30);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you post what you have so far? It's always nice for folks to have a starting point :)

Comment: It is always best to compose a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates what you have done so far, so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: I'd have put that but all I got is just a x and y axis. I could draw circles and squares separately but I'm not sure how to place them.

Comment: Good start. Now add `\draw (0,20) circle (5pt) node [left] {$t_2$}` to place the circle.

Comment: Do you know how to make the line inside the circle disappear?

Comment: Is there some specific name for this type of diagram? Because in the current form nobody that wants to create something similar is ever going to find this question, making it relatively useless. The question title would be better as `How can I create a <diagramname> diagram using LaTeX?`.

Comment: I modified the title, from some papers I found it appears that the diagram is to determine the results of a skyline operation. If this is not the case, then please edit the question to reflect what the diagram *is* for.

Comment: There is no specific name yet or else I would have given it a name. It's not even the skyline you are talking about. I gave it a temporary name. I'm working on a research that is currently in progress. The title skyline might be misleading as this has nothing to do with that.

Comment: Ok, that's weird. Since it matches the form (pretty much exactly) of some of the pictures I found in papers. It also corresponds with concepts from those papers, such as domination in a certain subdomain and the following min/max conclusions. Therefore, eventhough you might not have meant it for this purpose, I think we can leave the title as is. People looking to draw that kind of diagrams will probably find this helpfull. On a side note, you should add @name at the start of your post, so whoever you respond to gets a notification.

Comment: @wh1t3 Sure. I highly appreciate you taking effort in looking into the stuff.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the following code. The circles are created using nodes and we draw to and from the nodes, because then the line does not go through it. For the circle in the rectangle we define a new shape so we can just use nodes for that as well. The code looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{rectCircle}{
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle] % this is nearly a rectangle
  \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{east}
  \backgroundpath{% this is new
    % store lower left in xa/ya and upper right in xb/yb
    \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
    \northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y

    \pgfmathsetmacro{\temp@x}{\pgf@xa+.5*(\pgf@xb-\pgf@xa)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ttemp@x}{.5*(\pgf@xb-\pgf@xa)}    % construct main path
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathclose
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\temp@x}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpatharc{270}{-90}{\ttemp@x}
 }
}
\makeatother
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
    \node [circle, draw, minimum size=2.5mm, inner sep=0pt] (t1) at (3,0) {};
    \node [rectCircle, draw] (t5) at (0,2) {};
    \node [circle, draw, minimum size=2.5mm, inner sep=0pt] (t2) at (0,3) {};
    \node [circle, draw, minimum size=2.5mm, inner sep=0pt] (t4) at (2,2) {};
    \node [rectCircle, draw] (t3) at (2,1) {};
    \coordinate (orig) at (0,0);
  \draw (orig) -- (t1) node [below=2mm] {$t_1$};
  \draw [->] (t1) -- ++(0.5,0);
  \draw (orig) -- (t5) node[left=2mm]{$t_5$} -- (t2) node[left=2mm] {$t_2$};
  \draw [->] (t2) -- ++(0,0.5);
  \draw [dashed] (t5) -- (t4) node[right=2mm] {$t_4$} -- (t3) node[right=2mm] {$t_3$};
  \draw [dashed] (t2) -- ++(3,0) node {$\times$} -- (t1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the resulting image looks like this:

[image: diagram]

The most difficult part is the creation of the new node shape, I suppose. This could probably also be done by using `overlay` and `remember picture` and drawing the nodes on top of each other. That would require very precise sizing though and wouldn't scale as easily as creating a new shape. Creating the legend is left as an exercise for the reader, should be relatively straightforward now all of the nodes are available.

Answer (score 0):

Following code shows an alternative way for creating a `rectCircle` shape. Instead of declaring a new shape, just a style with an `append after command` option can serve.

Also a `cross` style has been declared which will replace `$\times$` in Roelof's solution.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,
        myCircle/.style={circle, draw, minimum size=2.5mm, inner sep=0pt},
        rectCircle/.style={myCircle,
            append after command={
                \pgfextra
                    \draw (\tikzlastnode.north-|\tikzlastnode.west) rectangle 
                          (\tikzlastnode.south-|\tikzlastnode.east);
                \endpgfextra}},
        cross/.style={cross out, minimum size=1.5mm, draw, inner sep=0pt, solid}
            ]
    \node [myCircle] (t1) at (3,0) {};
    \node [rectCircle, draw] (t5) at (0,2) {};
    \node [myCircle] (t2) at (0,3) {};
    \node [myCircle] (t4) at (2,2) {};
    \node [rectCircle, draw] (t3) at (2,1) {};
    \coordinate (orig) at (0,0);
  \draw (orig) -- (t1) node [below=2mm] {$t_1$};
  \draw [->] (t1) -- ++(0.5,0);
  \draw (orig) -- (t5) node[left=2mm]{$t_5$} -- (t2) node[left=2mm] {$t_2$};
  \draw [->] (t2) -- ++(0,0.5);
  \draw [dashed] (t5) -- (t4) node[right=2mm] {$t_4$} --(t3) node[right=2mm] {$t_3$};
  \draw [dashed] (t2) -- ++(3,0) node[cross] {} -- (t1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]